# How to refresh toolbar with every component or page visit (every time when any resource is used)

Tags: typescript, ionic4, angular8

I have an Ionic app written which displays a toolbar for every page. This toolbar contains a badge showing unread messages to the logged user (sceenshot attached). The toolbar component reads unread messages from the service in ngOnInit method.

[image]

Component html file:

```
<ion-header>
<ion-toolbar color="dark">
    <ion-title>
        <h5>{{title}}</h5>
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
        <ion-back-button defaultHref="profiles/guardian-profile"></ion-back-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-buttons slot="secondary">
        <ion-button>
            <ion-badge *ngIf="unreadNotifications" color="danger" [routerLink]="'/guardian-profile/guardian-notices'">{{unreadNotifications}}</ion-badge>
            <ion-badge *ngIf="!unreadNotifications"color="danger" [routerLink]="'/guardian-profile/guardian-notices'">{{announcementsNo}}</ion-badge>
        </ion-button>
        <ion-button (click)="logout()">
            <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="exit"></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
</ion-toolbar>
```

Component ts file:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {BaseHeaderClass} from '../../common/base-header-class';
import {EventService} from '../../services/event.service';
import {AuthService} from '../../services/auth.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-guardian-header',
    templateUrl: './guardian-header.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./guardian-header.component.scss'],
})
export class GuardianHeaderComponent extends BaseHeaderClass implements OnInit {

    @Input() headerTitle: string;
    @Input() unreadNotifications: number;
    announcementsNo: number;

    constructor(private eventService: EventService, protected authService: AuthService, protected router: Router) {
        super(authService, router);
    }

    getData() {
        this.eventService.getActiveNoticesOfLoggedGuardian().subscribe(res => {
            this.announcementsNo = res.length;
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        if (this.headerTitle) {
            this.title = this.headerTitle;
        } else {
            this.title = 'School Mate - Guardian View';
        }
        this.getData();
    }

    ionViewWillEnter() {
        this.getData();
    }
}
```

Now, when I read a message and then navigate between my components and pages the number of messages is being updated but only in these places where I haven't been before. If I visited particular place before the number of messages says unchanged.
I need this to be updated every time when I go anywhere, regardless I visited the place before or not.

Also I don't want to sent that number to the component with @Input() variable, I want it to stay self managed as it is now (my component still has this injection and I want to get rid of it). I need my toolbar to refresh unread messages whenever necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subscribe to the navigation route changes, so every time that the user navigates to another route, the event should emit a new value.

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}

ngOnInit() {
        this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
            if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
                // your code goes here
            }
         });
}
```

I hope this could be helpful. Good luck! :)